# Spring batch remote partitioning with multi threaded workers and dynamic scaling of workers

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

While learning about spring batch, I learnt that spring batch scaling approach of remote partitioning with message channel partition handler works very well. But it looks like, it’s not possible to create workers dynamically(such as horizontally scaling kubernetes pods) in this case. The workers needs to be up and running to process each partition. Can it be wise approach to make each worker as multi threaded step with task executer? If yes, can each thread within a worker process a message each and pick new message when finished? And once cpu utilization of the worker pod reaches let’s say 70%, an horizontal auto scaler can create another pod. Once all messages are processed auto scaler can bring down the pods. I read that restartabilty is an issue with multi threaded approach, will that be an issue? Can input table where the input data is stored with a indicator, can solve this issue? Next time batch is run it can read only records with indicator not set. Please let me know your thoughts.

None